# Gaussian Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Mathematica tells me:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x\stackrel{n\neq0}{\equiv}0$$
My investigations give me on the one hand:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\left|\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n-1}}e^{-x^2}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\left|p_{n-1}(x)e^{-x^2}\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$$
and on the other hand they yield:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2n}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}a^n}\right|_{a=1}e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x\\=(-1)^n\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}a^n}\right|_{a=1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x=(-1)^n\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}a^n}\right|_{a=1}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdots\frac{2n-1}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}$$
Intuitively, the latter seems right also because I can't imagine all integrals to vanish, or do they?

*(Ok my problem got solved: I had an error in computing the derivatives.)*

Comment: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}a^n}\right|_{a=1}e^{-ax^2}$$ is not equal to $$x^{2n} e^{-x^2}$$. Chain rule

Comment: @tired: Why shouldn't it be equal? Chain rule gives you every time you differentiate one power of $−x^2$ to the front. Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{-x^2}$ belongs to the Schwarz space $\mathfrak{S}(\mathbb{R})$, hence your claim just follows from integration by parts, or from:

$$\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{d^m}{dx^m}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \left.\frac{d^{m-1}}{dx^{m-1}}e^{-x^2}\right|_{-M}^{M}\ll\frac{1}{M}.$$

Comment: But how can all integrals vanish; looking at its graph doesn't seem so, or?

Comment: Looking at the graph of what? The gaussian function is "flatter and flatter" as $|x|\to +\infty$.

Comment: The area below the x-axis compared to the one above...

Comment: @Freeze_S: you have to look at the graphics of the derivatives.

Comment: Yes but it's just unbelievable that they really cancel each other, or? For example the first derivative has two bumps above the x-axis one on the left and one mirrored on the right and only one bump below the x-axis and also totally different in shape and size. They really cancel each other? Wooow! :)

Comment: Still the question in my mind: How can it happen that the second method gives so wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

By the main theorem of integral calculus, your integral is $\big[\frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}x}e^{-x^2}\big]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$.

But the $n-1$-derivative just gives you a linear combination of polynomials times the Gaussian function,so

$I=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left[a_ix^ie^{-x^2}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$

Now, note that $e^{-x^2}$ decreases faster to zero then every polynomial at $\pm\infty$, which means $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^i e^{-x^2}=0$,for $i\geq0 $.

So every term of the sum vanishes independently, which means that the whole integral is zero.

Comment: But how can all integrals vanish; looking at its graph doesn't seem so, or?

Comment: the integral for $n=i$  is determined by the value of the endpoints of the function $\frac{d^{i-1}}{d^{i-1}x}e^{-x^2}$ which are zero, which can be easily seen by plotting a few examples.

Comment: Yes but imagine you take aaany polynomial function. Then they all yield that the area their derivative strives out below and above are always the same, isn't that super weird?

Comment: Take $\int_a^b f'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$. It's obvious, that the result doesn't depend on an details of $f$ in the interval $[a,b]$. I think this shows the real power of the fundamental theorem.

Comment: Still the question in my mind: How can it happen that the second method gives so wrong results?

Comment: @Freeze_S: you are computing two different integrals. The fact that $\int \frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}e^{-x^2}\,dx = 0$ does not imply that $\int x^{2n} e^{-x^2}\,dx$ must be zero. The moments are a thing, the derivatives another one.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Ok I had an error in computations; everythings fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\left.%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\totald[n]{\expo{-x^{2}}}{x}\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{\,n\ \geq\ 1}}
=\lim_{y\ \to 0}\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\totald[n]{\expo{-\pars{x + y}^{\,2}}}{x}\,\dd x
=\lim_{y\ \to 0}\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\totald[n]{\expo{-\pars{x + y}^{\,2}}}{y}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{y\ \to 0}\ \partiald[n]{}{y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-\pars{x + y}^{\, 2}}\,\dd x
=\lim_{y\ \to 0}\ \partiald[n]{}{y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
=\lim_{y\ \to 0}\ 0=\color{#66f}{\large 0}
\end{align}